# How a Convolutional Neural Net handles channels

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, convolution

I've looked through a lot of explanations of the way a CNN conventionally handles multiple channels (such as 3 in an RGB image) and am still at a loss.

When a 5x5x3 filter (say) is applied to a patch of an RGB image what *exactly* happens? Is it in fact 3 different 2D convolutions (with independent weights) that happen separately to each channel? And then the results get simply added together to produce the final output to pass to the next layer? Or is it a truly 3D convolution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

This image is from Andrew Ng's deeplearning.ai course. 6 X 6 X 3 - where 3 corresponds to 3 color channels.
6 X 6 being the height and widht of the image.
For the convolution step we convolve the input image with 3 X 3 X 3 filter/kernel. The input image and filter both will have 3 layers. (Mostly both are same for input image and filter).The output will be 4 X 4 X 1.
3 X 3 X 3 gives you 27 features/parameters which you multiply with the corresponding Red, Green and blue channels. Finally add up all those numbers to get the value for [0,0] in 4 X 4 output image. Now move the yellow cube of the input image and slide it over 1 box to your right and  once it reaches the right end, you slide the cube one row down and continue your multiplication to fill the 4 X 4 output. Would suggest you to take a paper and pencil, fill random values in all the cubes for input as well as the kernel and solve the multiplication.

For more details watch these lectures on youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTB_OFoAQcc&index=6&list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Gl29AoE31iwdVwSG-KnDzF

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7g8jpK4llkc&t=1s

Comment: Ah ok, so it is literally just a 3D convolution at the first layer to deal with the RGB-ness and following that it behaves exactly like a CNN applied to a 1 channel image. Have I understood that right? Thanks for you help!

Comment: You usually want to apply **multiple** 3D-Kernels (e.g. a **D**-number of 'yellow cubes') to your first input RGB-layer, which will result in a **multiple** feature-maps. The *deeper* conv-layer will have a size of N*N***D**.

Comment: If you have 20 kernels the next filters, in the next convolutional layers, will be of size (X , Y , 20) ?  I have seen plots of intermediate filters (working with many channels) in cnns and they always plot 2D (?)

Answer (score 1):

The formula to calculate the filter size is for the Convolutional layer as the below:

- Accepts a volume of size W1 × H1 × D1
- Requires four hyperparameters:

  - Number of filters K,
  - Their spatial extent F (filter size F x F )
  - The stride S
  - The amount of zero padding PP.
- Produces a volume of size ( W2 × H2 × D2 ) where:

  - W2 = (W1 − F + 2P)/S + 1
  - H2 = (H1 − F + 2P)/S + 1  (i.e. width and height are computed equally by symmetry)
  - D2 = K
- With parameter sharing, it introduces (F × F × D1) weights per filter, for a total of ( F × F × D1) × K weights and K biases.
- In the output volume, the d-th depth slice (of size W2 × H2 ) is the result of performing a valid convolution of the d-th filter over the input volume with a stride of S, and then offset by d-th bias.

for more details [see this link](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)

[image]